# Count appearance of dates on each row

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with name and datetimes which looks like this.

```
name, date_1, date_2, date_3, ..., date_100
A, 2020-07-01, 2020-07-3,2020-07-04,..., 2020-11-30
B, 2020-07-02, 2020-07-02, 2020-07-06,..., NaT
```

I want to count how many times each person appears from 2020-07-01 to 2020-11-30.
So the output should look like this.

```
name, 2020-07-01, 2020-07-02,...,2020-11-30
A, 1, 0, ..., 1
B, 0, 2, ..., 0
```

I have tried this but this returns not what I need.

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['date_1'])
df.groupby(by=[df.index.day])

Output:
date_1, name, date_1, date_2, ... date_100
2020-07-01, A, 2020-07-01, 2020-07-3,2020-07-04,..., 2020-11-30
2020-07-03, B, 2020-07-02, 2020-07-02, 2020-07-06,..., NaT
```

Is there any function to count appearance of dates on each row?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try `melt` to convert the date into a column and `crosstab` to count co-occurrences:

```
melt_df = df.melt('name', value_name='date').dropna()

pd.crosstab(melt_df['name'], melt_df['date'])
```